# android emulator won't open in a window

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, window, emulation

I'm running Eclipse Indigo on Ubuntu and my Android emulator won't open. The window doesn't even show up.

It used to work but I updated something (forget what) and now it doesn't. When the console feels like working it'll say the emulator is launching but the window never opens. When I try to delete the AVDs it says that it's running in an emulator and cannot be deleted but there is still no window.

I've re-installed AVDs the ADT and still nothing. Could anyone help me out? I tried it outside of Eclipse in ./android and it still won't open.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and so far the only workaround I found was to restart my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you open the AVD manager, either from Eclipse or just from your machine? If you can, do you see any emulators listed there? What happens when you click start? Maybe your emulator(s) were deleted and the AVD manager can't find any to launch when you go to launch an Android application.

Comment: If you mean the AVD manager, a window called launch options opens then if I hit launch it says starting emulator for AVD 'XXX'. Then a progress bar fills all the way, and then nothing happens. Don't know where in the SDK manager you'd find emulators.

Comment: Yes I meant AVD manager. Sorry man I'm not sure what you should try next. I'd try creating a new Android virt device and starting it. If a brand new one doesn't work then I'd nuke everything and start over. Android sucks like this sometimes.

Comment: So where would you begin with me nuking everything? I've tried that and I guess I didn't really nuke everything.

Comment: Honestly, I would ditch using the emulator. I've never had good success with the emulator mostly because it's so slow and glitchy compared to my phone. I'd look for a cheap android device on eBay or something and run it on that.